# SYMBIAN, QT, C++

Tags: c++, qt, symbian

I need to code simple app for symbian, but I cant find anything information how to prepare environment for that. I really need simple how to code "hello world" to symbian with instruction how to prepare environment for any os(linux, windows only without ios)

Answer (score 3):

You would have spent less time just googling "Symbian hello world":
http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Symbian_C%2B%2B_Hello_World

And here is the complete api, including a "Getting started" section:
http://www.developer.nokia.com/document/Cpp_Developers_Library/